# Number of checks to find the median of a set of random 16 numbers

Tags: algorithm, math

Our teacher gave us a problem to program a way to figure the number of checks needed to find the median of a set of 16 random numbers using a decision tree. he also told us that the least possible number of checks would be 2N, however when we did it on a paper we came out with 27 checks, we double checked our work and everything was right. So is their a definitive answer for min number of checks?

Comment: This question should be asked on http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: doesn't that same as sorting an array and finding a particular element?

Comment: dam sorry i totally forgoten about the math one

Comment: Since this is about programming an algorithm, I don't see how it would be math.se, and not SO.  @ADG sorting the array would let you find the median in constant time, but the sorting would take `O(N log N)` first.

Answer (score 0):

The paper "Samuel W. Bent and John W. John. Finding the median requires 2n comparisons. In Proceedings
of the Seventeenth Annual ACM Symposium on Theory of Computing, pages 213{216, 1985." proves that 2n is a lower bound.

This paper requires access to ACM, but there is an alternative proof on page 3 of "ON LOWER BOUNDS FOR SELECTING THE MEDIAN" available [here](http://www.nada.kth.se/~johanh/mediansdma.pdf).

Perhaps you could explain your proposed solution?